# How do I access this scope variable inside of isolated scope directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my situation in psuedo code

```
<div data-ng-controller="test">

    <div isolated-directive>
        <select ng-model="testControllerScopeVar">...</select>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="some condition that uses testControllerScopeVar"></div>

</div>
```

This worked perfectly before I added `isolated-directive`, now that it is added (`scope: true`) the `ng-if` no longer works because I think it is getting eat up inside of the directive.

What is the most efficient way to get this working without touching the structure of the html and `isolated-directive`?

Comment: have you enabled transclusion on your isolated-directive (e.g. `transclude: true`) and included an `<ng-transclude>` tag in the isolated-directive's template?

Comment: Dont you think it is a little counter intuitive creating a model inside isolated scope, yet referencing that model outside of that scope?

Comment: @rob no but I don't want to touch that directive

Comment: @Yerken the directive is a complex dockable directive but the design requires this dropdown to be inside of the dockable so it docks. The content that show/hide is based on the dropdown. What else can I do?

Comment: The only way to do this is to modify isolated-directive. You would either need to enable transclusion, remove it's isolate scope, or pass the variable out as @Jack A. suggested

Comment: @rob figured it out using controllerAs, posted answer, thanks for your time

Comment: @Huangism my bad. I was thinking your `isolated-directive` used an isolate scope but I see now that you mentioned it uses and inherited scope (`scope: ture`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems once I know the solution, it is so simple

```
<div data-ng-controller="test as testCtrl">

    <div isolated-directive>
        <select ng-model="testCtrl.testControllerScopeVar">...</select>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="testCtrl.testControllerScopeVar == 'whatever'"></div>

</div>
```

ControllerAs allows me to specifically access the right scope and works perfectly, thanks all for your time and input

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to map the controller variable into your isolated scope and attach the isolated scope variable to your internal `ng-model`.

So your HTML would look like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="test">

    <div isolated-directive="testControllerScopeVar">
        <select ng-model="isolatedScopeVar">...</select>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="some condition that uses testControllerScopeVar"></div>

</div>
```

And your directive declaration would look like this:

```
app.directive('isolatedDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            isolatedScopeVar: '=isolatedDirective'
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the directive at all because it is a very complex directive that does its own thing well. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Huangism It's hard to say what options you have without knowing more about the directive in question. Have you tried what you want to do yet? If the directive does not transclude and does not use a template, then it will work as you have it written. See this fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/ouh1yax3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery to get the value and assign it to a new scope variable. Something like this

HTML

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="test">
    <div isolated-directive>
      <input id="isolatedVar" ng-model="testControllerScopeVar" />
    </div>
    <div>
      {{isolatedVar}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
   var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
    app.controller('test', function($scope) {
      var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#isolatedVar'));
      element.bind('keyup', function() {
        $scope.isolatedVar = element.val();
        console.log($scope.isolatedVar);
        $scope.$watch('isolatedVar', function() {});

      });

    });
    app.directive('isolatedDirective', function() {
      return {
        scope: true
      };
    });
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kavinio/yzb8ouzd/1/

Comment: No jquery on this project and it is not needed, I figured out the solution and posted it as answer